# How to disable xscreensaver lock on suspend?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, lock-screen, screensaver, xscreensaver

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have installed `xscreensaver`.

As I am the only user on this computer and I am only using the computer for music, movies, and some web browsing  I have no need for the extra security of a lock screen.

Under user accounts, automatic login is turned on.
Under brightness and lock, the lock is turned off and requires my password when waking from suspend is unchecked.
Under `xscreensaver` preferences, the lock screen box is unchecked.

Every time the computer goes into suspend I get an `xscreensaver` lock screen upon waking it. Is there a setting I'm missing or something?

From what I understand removing `xscreensaver` will fix this, but I would consider that a last resort if I can not resolve this issue as I like to use my photos as a screensaver.

I have just begun using Linux and don't know what I'm doing so your patience and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: just to be sure that the problem is really xscreensaver, can you turn off xscreensaver (simply execute `killall xscreensaver`, no need to uninstall it), then suspend your computer, wake it up again and check if the problem persists?

Comment: The login screen I receive looks nothing like the normal ubuntu login screen, the screen is black and in the middle is a box that say xscreensaver on it.
To be certain I followed your instruction and as expected once xscreensaver was shut down everything worked normally, without a login screen.

Comment: Digging for answers to this, I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/95295/how-to-prevent-screen-locking-when-lid-is-closed. Please have a look, one of those answers may solve your problem. If you think your question may be a duplicate of that thread, please flag it so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Login Prompt after Screensaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555732/disable-login-prompt-after-screensaver)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this AskUbuntu [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130808/stop-xscreensaver-from-locking-screen-once-screensaver-starts).

Basically, you should also disable screen locking in power manager settings

If you are not using power manager, you can try to comment out line `LOCK_SCREEN=TRUE in /etc/default/acpi-support`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *that you have* -- ***only one GUI***. *Which GUI generates its different configuration file and sometimes messes up with programs* including screensaver settings.

I resolved the same problem as yours by  *installing only one GUI* -- *cinnamon as an example*, or you can *try another interface* and I highly recommend using **Tweak Tool/Power Management**.