# Disable Login Prompt after Screensaver

Tags: 14.04, gnome-screensaver

I want the screensaver on, but when I move the mouse over the screen, I don't want to be prompted for the password.

Is there any way of doing this?

I see that the screensaver setting has been removed since version 11, and been replaced with GNOME Screensaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes go into screen saver lock settings under system settings and disable prompt for password on resume and or screensaver...

Comment: I don't see that on 14.04 - unless it is hidden?

Comment: I found in `Brightness & Lock` > `Require my password when waking from suspend`. I unticked that, but not sure if that was correct?

Comment: By the way, I found the setting in the privacy section, on Ubuntu 16.04 (for anyone using that version).