# Laptop doesn't hibernate when I close the lid in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lid

Ok, I know there already are several questions related to this. I tried many solutions to no avail. I'm going to detail here what I did and how are my config files in the hope that a good soul will point out what I missed.

Some initial information:

- I installed Ubuntu 14 from a 14.01 .iso and it became a 14.04
  because, I guess, I checked an option to update automatically during
  the install.
- I have an external monitor attached. This seems to be relevant in
  some cases.
- As explaned [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/), there is no option to make the PC hibernate in
  the power settings of Ubuntu 14. Only suspend and do nothing.
- `pm-hibernate` works fine.
- My swap is slightly larger than my RAM

**1.**
I had a Mint (14 if I'm not mistaken) where closing the lid would not hibernate until I [added some scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291903/ubuntu-not-is-hibernating-when-lid-is-closed/375542#375542). In Ubuntu 14 there is no `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` that I can edit as I did in Mint. I tried to create one with the following contents:

```
echo 'ok' > ok
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    su - gabriel -c 'dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action' | grep hibernate
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        pm-hibernate
    fi
fi
```

The file `ok` is not created when I close the lid, this means the script is never called.

I tried to move lid.sh into `events/`.

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64570/how-do-i-configure-the-screen-to-lock-when-i-close-the-lid/68483#68483), I tried to rename it to `lid.sh.post` and to move it to `/etc/acpi/local/`, and other several combinations of directory and names (with/without `.post`, in `/etc/acpi/`, `local/`, `events/`...)

**2.**
I did as told [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64570/how-do-i-configure-the-screen-to-lock-when-i-close-the-lid/68483#68483) and installed `gnome-tweak-tool`, so I could set the action on closed lid to hibernate. After I did, the dropdowns in the control panel / power were blank (not suspend nor 'do nothing'), but now they show 'do nothing' again, I don't know what I did to change that. And running

```
su - gabriel -c 'dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action'
```

still returns 'nothing', which compromises my (probably useless anyway) script.

**3.**
I did as told [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-lts-when-the-lid-is-closed/): edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set `HandleLidSwitch` to 'hibernate':

```
cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep -i lid
#HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

I also tried with

```
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

**4.**
As explained [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation), I edited `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`:

```
root@gabriel-linux:/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d# cat com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla 
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: do you have a swap partition at least as large as your ram?

Comment: @sbergeron, yes

Comment: is it mounted when you try to hibernate?

Comment: Not sure how to check that... The Disks utility says it's "active". Is that ok ?

Comment: go into gparted and right click then if it says swapkon click it to turn it on and try again

Comment: Did you remove the `#` in front of your commands, such as `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` instead of `#HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe, I'm not sure anymore, it's been a long time, but I'm pretty sure I did remove those `#`. Can't have been that distracted, right ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my script (`lid.sh`) to be called in `/etc/acpi/`, I had to create the correct file in `/etc/acpi/events/`.

The file has to be called `lm_lid` and the content is as follows:

```
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

Reboot your system to let this take effect.

**Note:** I moved back to Linux Mint (now 17) before I figured this all out, and this, with the correct file, now works. I'd like to hear from Ubuntu users though.

Comment: related: [Catch lid close and open events](http://askubuntu.com/a/526003)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Linux Mint 17.3. It went away when I installed the nvidia video driver in the place of the default open source one. (Administration->Driver Manager->Select nvidia recommended driver)